# An identity in C* algebra

Tags: operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a C* algebra and $a,x \in A$. Is the identity $x^*a^*ax \leq \|a\|^2 x^*x$ true ? How to prove it?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the axioms for a C*-algebra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Here are two useful propositions for proving this:

1. For any positive element $a$ in a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$, we have $a\leq \|a\|$
2. If $a,b\in A$ and $a$ is positive, then $b^*ab$ is positive.

Comment: Can you give me a hint to prove 1? How about in non unital case? In my context we are not assuming unital.

Comment: For 1 use the fact that $a\in A$ is positive if and only if $a$ is self-adjoint and $\sigma(a)\subset[0,\infty)$, where $\sigma(a)$ is the spectrum of $a$.  The non-unital case is reduced to the unital case by attaching a unit.

Comment: yes i could prove it thank you so much